# Django-allauth - OpenID and OAuth redirect + Apache as Proxy

Tags: python, django, apache, gunicorn, django-allauth

I'm trying to enable a login via Steam based on OpenID.

My env is pretty simple, django runs with gunicorn @ 8000, Apache @ 80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.example.com

    # Point this to your public folder of teambox
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/dev.example.com/Example/

    # Custom log file locations
    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/dev.example.com_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/dev.example.com_access.log combined

    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    <Location />
        ProxyPassReverse /
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

In both cases I get the following error

```
ERROR:root:Missing required parameter in response from https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login: ('http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0', 'assoc_type')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/openid/message.py", line 455, in getArg
    return self.args[args_key]
KeyError: ('http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0', 'assoc_type')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/openid/consumer/consumer.py", line 1280, in _requestAssociation
    assoc = self._extractAssociation(response, assoc_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/openid/consumer/consumer.py", line 1397, in _extractAssociation
    OPENID_NS, 'assoc_type', no_default)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/openid/message.py", line 458, in getArg
    raise KeyError((namespace, key))
KeyError: ('http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0', 'assoc_type')
```

Now the strange (to me) part is, if I connect directly to 8000, the redirect does work even though it produces the error in the background, but via 80 it doesn't. The strangest part is, the redirect returned by Django is different.

:80 via Apache

`example.com/nl/openid/login/?process=login&openid=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid`

`example.com/nl/openid/login?openid.ax.mode=fetch_request&openid.ax.required=...`

`example.com/nl/openid/login/?openid.ax.mode=fetch_request&openid.ax.required=...`

:8000 case - direct connection to gunicorn

`example.com:8000/nl/openid/login/?process=login&openid=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid`

`https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ax.mode=fetch_request&openid.ax.required=...`

-- EDIT --

After some more testing it turns out that the Google OAuth has the same issue, redirecting me to my site `/o/oauth2/` instead of `google.com/o/oauth2/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some kicking, screaming and praying to the Apache gods it turn out my Apache config was wrong, the ProxyPassReverse was faulty

```
ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
<Location />
    # ProxyPassReverse /
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Location>
```